# How to send notification to all users

Tags: getstream-io

I want to send notification to all users that are following me.

in the e.g,

```
$activity = array('actor'=>$user->username, 'verb'=>'ping', 'object'=>$ping->id);
$feed = $client->feed('notification', $pingTarget->id);
$feed->addActivity($activity);
```

what will be the value of object $ping->id and $pingTarget->id.

how we can send notification to multiple users that are following me

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to create a follow connection between user feed and its followers' notification feeds.

eg. if user A, B and C follows user D you should create the following connections:

```
$client->feed('notification', 'user:A')->follow('timeline', 'user:D');
$client->feed('notification', 'user:B')->follow('timeline', 'user:D');
$client->feed('notification', 'user:C')->follow('timeline', 'user:D');
```

Activities added to the feed of user D will be delivered to followers' notification feeds.

Comment: I tried this but nothing happen. no notification found. i created timeline feed type from admin section. Am I missing anything ?